# Get Tweet Id using Tweepy TwitterV2

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to make a bot which makes a post and then self replies. The only issue I am having is that response.id is not fetching the tweet id. Could I get any pointers as to the right way to fetch the id of a tweet that was just posted?

```
# Post Tweet
response = client.create_tweet(text=tweet_msg)

# Respond to first tweet posted
client.create_tweet(text=reply_msg, in_reply_to_tweet_id=response.id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was actually wondering how to do this myself and just figured it out. When you create a tweet and print it you should notice a response in your terminal. It should look something like this.

Response(data={'edit_history_tweet_ids': ['ID_IS_HERE'], 'id': 'ID_IS_HERE', 'text': 'TWEET_TEXT_IS_HERE'.

To access the id you'll have to say have to say the following

```
# Post Tweet
response = client.create_tweet(text=tweet_msg)

# Respond to first tweet posted
client.create_tweet(text=reply_msg, in_reply_to_tweet_id=response.data['id'])
```

You're accessing the ID of the tweet with the response.data['id'] part, hope this helps.